# Disk monitor script with long file systems

Tags: linux, bash, diskmanagement

```
$ df -H
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_app001-lv_root
                        34G    12G    21G  35% /
tmpfs                  8.4G      0   8.4G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              508M    54M   429M  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_app001-lv_home
                        19G   309M    17G   2% /home
```

I want to run a disk monitor script but because the filesystem is so long the row has been split into two lines and the script fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df -P`
It will use posix format

Comment: what exactly is posix format?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX - basically, it's a defined standard to which all Unix-like POSIX compliant operating systems 'try' to adhere.  It defines the format of a lot of stuff.

Comment: Do people still recommend setting LANG=C in scripts before interpreting the output from commands, in case LANG=somethingweird causes your script to fail?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this line:

```
df -PTlk -x smbfs -x tmpfs -x cifs -x iso9660 -x udf -x nfsv4 | sed 1d
```

(stolen from [Check-MK Agent](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk.html))